# Reducing size of data stored with JSON

Tags: c#

I have data that I convert to JSON. I need storage to be very optimized but when I look at the JSON string there is a lot of wasted space. For example my single true of false gets converted to:

```
"testField":false
```

It might seem not much but I have a lot of data and it's a big problem when one byte of a true or false gets converted to something 15 times larger.

Is there anything I could do to stop this huge waste of space and to optimize the way data is stored. Note that I don't really need it to be JSON. All I need is to take the data stored in a class and have it converted to a string that I can convert back later.

Comment: -1 This is to generic.  Give some specific examples of /your/ data.  Don't just complain about the format you chose.

Comment: This is an example of my data. Not sure what else I can give. This is the way data is stored in JSON. Data is stored with a label and the word true or false. It uses a lot of space.

Comment: If it is always the same field, why not return a value like this: 10000101011011  (or even more succinctly, a byte [] where each byte represents 8 boolean values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could change testField into an integer and set it to "0".
That would be smaller than "false".

Comment: yeah this sounds like a possibility. Still seems like a lot of space is wasted

Comment: I like your idea best. Actually I changed it to a string and changed field name. That saves a lot of space ,"TF":""

Answer (score 1):

Check out MessagePack: http://msgpack.org/

Comment: This looks like a possibility but is anyone using it? Also I have classes, containing classes, containg arrays. Not sure how deep msgpack can go with serialization.

Comment: Anything you can serialize with JSON can be serialized with messagepack. I'm not sure how many people are using it but it seems like there are a good amount of tweets about it: http://twitter.com/#!/search/realtime/MessagePack%20OR%20msgpack

Answer (score 0):

testField is the name of your property, no?

If you'd like that shorter, use a shorter property name, but you're still only having a Boolean returned as the value.  I guess if you don't like true/false you can make sure a 0/1 is returned instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use a binary format (BSon), or even better, Google's Protocol Buffers